# How to remove all content before and after two different HTML tags from the Linux command line

Tags: html, string, bash, sed

I have a file, *links.html*, and want to remove everything before:

```
<div id="data_div"
```

and everything after **AND** including

```
<div style="\"overflow:auto\"">
```

and save to a new file; *links1.html*.

Is it possible to complete this in a single operation, either with BASH string manipulation or sed?

If so, how?

Comment: Yes. Yes it is. If you want to know how, well, that's a whole other question...

Comment: I'm too noob for this.. should I delete and re-post?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html)

Comment: Thanks Cyrus. I tried a few sed's but keep getting caught with escaping the characters.

Comment: You should edit your question to make it specific and answerable.

Comment: Are the `<div id="data_div"` and the `<div style="\"overflow:auto\"">` at the beginning of a line?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is entirely possible. Below are two examples, although you will have to substitute "pattern" with what you referenced above as the pattern.

To remove everything after a "pattern" to include the pattern itself, you can use the following command

```
sed -i '/pattern/,$d' filename
```

To remove everything before a pattern to include the pattern itself, you can use the following command

```
sed -i '1,/pattern/d' filename
```

If you would like to not edit the file in place, you could remove the "-i" portion and redirect the output to a separate file.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question at all. OP wants to know about all lines after matching lines too. Also, how to remove the head of the file?

Comment: His original question was "Is it possible?" before he edited his post. Which I answered, and then I gave him an example answering the second part of his question to point him in the right direction.

 I showed him that with "sed" he can delete everything after a pattern. I also added a piece on how to delete everything up to a pattern in a file. He can replace the ${pattern} portion with what he would like to have replaced.